# Selecting the next results in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select the next result just by specifying the name?

I have a table that looks like this, no IDs, just list of usernames.

```
row1 = username(Alex) 
row2 = username(Bob) 
row3 = username(Britney) 
row4 = username(Steve) 
row5 = username(Courtney) 
row6 = username(Greg) 
row7 = username(Abul) 
row8 = username(Roger) 
row9 = username(Victoria) 
row10 = username(Brooke)
```

Let's say, I want to select all Items after 'Greg'. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the table definition?  Do you have some ordinal number for the users?

Comment: Nope, just a list of usernames

Comment: If the only field in the table is username, then there is no guarantee that Alex will always be the first user. SQL tables have no inherent sorting.

Comment: What's the point of using a db then? What if you have two Gregs?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no inherent ordering of tables in SQL, so there is no way (other than by alphabetical order) to determine which name comes next.

In fact, the order displayed in the question is entirely arbitrary - without a specified `order by` clause, retrieval order of rows is essentially random.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by two query..first find the id of the particular name.
like select id from tablename where username='Greg'
then fetching that id,
select * from tablename where id>fetching id.

Comment: He said he does have any ID fields... unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Add ID column to your table, and then use LIMIT as offset

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT (SELECT ID FROM username WHERE username='Greg'), MAX(ID)
```

Didn't tested, but you can play with it